# Customizing client texts in Unblu

Tags: tomcat

I am using Unblu co-browsing tool and would like to customize some client texts.

[Unblu FAQ](https://www.unblu.com/en/doc/latest/articles/faq.html) says: "The message is displayed only on the client side. The texts are easily configurable by properties.", but does not mention how.

[Unblu Text properties Doc](https://www.unblu.com/en/doc/latest/references/collaboration/text-properties.html) describes how to customize some texts, but I cannot find the ones I would like to alter:

- "How can I help you?"
- "Talk to one of our agents via live chat."
- "Establish co-browsing connection"
- "Have one of our agents join you via co-browsing"

I have Unblu 4.2.23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution at last. The property names can be found and modified the following way:

1. Log in to Unblu Agent Desk with superadmin
2. Settings > Global > Text > Advanced > Options: Show inherited,
   Technical labels
3. Then the properties can be modified here or in the unblu.properties
   file.

In this case in unbu.properties we should add a com.unblu.textoverlay=/.../unblu-text.properties property pointing to an unblu-text.properties file.
The unblu-text.properties file looks the following way:

```
chatdialog.description.en=Our support agent will help you with your questions.
chatdialog.name.en=Start chat or call with customer support 
...
```